# Formating Etherscan API Result ( JsonRpc )

Tags: jquery, json, api, blockchain

I've extracted an ABI Value ( using the Keccak hash method )

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_call&to=0xD2354AcF1a2f06D69D8BC2e2048AaBD404445DF6&data=0xd679677a&tag=latest

Sadly I don't how to "use" the result for html as I my Jquery Knowledge is not sufficient and I have to convert the result in Decimal.. ( it's in hexadecimal )

Any Help appriciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're just reading a number, web3 has methods that let you convert it from hex to an actual number. There's plenty of examples in the web3 docs

Comment: Thank you but I failed at implementing web3.js..  I was using this Setup       
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("use infura acces token here")); 
ABI = "here all the ABI string"
var pyramidContract = web3.eth.contract(ABI);
var pyramidInstance = contrato.at('0xBc1869a652F68260428b382fd06C96196D92d02D')
pyramidInstance.buyPrice(function(err,result){
    console.log(result) // this is the returned value
})

Comment: I've managed to get web3.js running.. But need to figure out the Output Process.. But thank you anyway